# How do you create a custom message based on the HTTP status code using JQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using jQuery I would like to create a custom message based off of the returned data HTTP status codes. I created a condition displaying a unique message based off of the returned status code but I am getting the following error message:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined:**

My jQuery script is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


      $('#submitButton').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({

              url: 'myUrl',
              type: 'post',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: $('form#Form').serialize(),
              success: function(data) {

                          if (data.code == '201') {

                            alert('New Resource Created');

                          }

                          if (data.code == '1000') {

                            alert('Successful message');

                          }                      


              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error){

                          if (data.code == '400') {

                            alert('Bad Request!');

                          }


                          if (data.code == '2004') {

                            alert('System error message!');

                          }

              } 

              // Prevent default form action


          });
      });


    });
```

The JSON code that I'm receiving uses the following format:

```
{
 "status": "400",
 "code": "2003",
 "message": "Invalid address copy"
}
```

Here is an example of the status codes:

```
201 – OK 
2004 - System error message!
400 - Invalid address copy
```

My HTML Form is here:

```
<form id="Form">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
 <input type="text" id="address1" placeholder="Address 1" name="address1">
 <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Not sure what I am missing on this or why I am getting an error but any help is welcomed.

Comment: `if (data.code== ` should be `if(status==`

Comment: you can get the status code using xhr as a param and checking xhr.status usually in your success function.

Comment: You are getting that error because when it goes into `error:`, data is not defined! Try with the `status` variable or use your `xhr` variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment before, try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#submitButton').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({

          url: 'myUrl',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: $('form#Form').serialize(),
          success: function(data) {

                      if (data.code == '201') {

                        alert('New Resource Created');

                      }

                      if (data.code == '1000') {

                        alert('Successful message');

                      }                      


          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error){

                      if (xhr.code == '400') {

                        alert('Bad Request!');

                      }


                      if (xhr.code == '2004') {

                        alert('System error message!');

                      }

          } 

          // Prevent default form action


      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm!